# javascript static files hot reload

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im looking for the simplest possible module to hot-reload a static folder with all its contents.
With hot-reload i mean that the browser reloads the page.

i tried [simple auto reload server](https://github.com/cytb/simple-autoreload-server)
i could not get it running and the config seems a bit over engineered for my use-case.

my best guess would be to write it myself in node, i cant be the first person who runs into that problem.

i dont want to use any taskrunner like webpack, grunt or gulp.
just to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [`five-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/five-server). Super great! First install Node.js, then

- `npm install five-server` in your project
- `npx five-server ./` and it will open a browser tab automatically, and will by default auto-reload your web app on file changes

An alternative is [BrowserSync](https://browsersync.io/docs), which offers more features, but is a bit more difficult to use, and some commands seem to not really work well:

- `npm install -g browser-sync`
- Run in console `browser-sync start --server --files "css/*.css"` . You can add any other files you need to reload like: `--files "css/*.css,js/*.js,pages/*.html"`
- Open the url provided by it, and it will reload the changes in any .css file in the css folder.

Comment: Thanks. that was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Tip: If you don't want to install browser-sync globally, you can use npx instead. Example: npx browser-sync start --server --files "css/*.css"